# MySQL SELECT incremental index based on value in a different column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I do the following SELECT

```
SELECT products.supplier_catalog_number, prices.price, 0 AS price_index
FROM products
  INNER JOIN prices ON prices.product_id = products.id
LIMIT 10
```

and the result looks like

```
+-------------------------+----------+-------------+
| supplier_catalog_number | price    | price_index |
+-------------------------+----------+-------------+
| 00000001600L            | 287.0000 |           0 |
| 00000001600L            | 243.9500 |           0 |
| 0023-200                | 710.0000 |           0 |
| 0023-200                | 603.5000 |           0 |
| 0023-300                | 232.0000 |           0 |
| 0023-300                | 185.6000 |           0 |
| 0023-301                | 289.0000 |           0 |
| 0023-301                | 231.2000 |           0 |
| 0023-301                | 109.0000 |           0 |
| 0023-301                |  92.6500 |           0 |
+-------------------------+----------+-------------+
```

I need the result to be

```
+-------------------------+----------+-------------+
| supplier_catalog_number | price    | price_index |
+-------------------------+----------+-------------+
| 00000001600L            | 287.0000 |           0 |
| 00000001600L            | 243.9500 |           1 |
| 0023-200                | 710.0000 |           0 |
| 0023-200                | 603.5000 |           1 |
| 0023-300                | 232.0000 |           0 |
| 0023-300                | 185.6000 |           1 |
| 0023-301                | 289.0000 |           0 |
| 0023-301                | 231.2000 |           1 |
| 0023-301                | 109.0000 |           2 |
| 0023-301                |  92.6500 |           3 |
+-------------------------+----------+-------------+
```

can it be done in a single query?

Comment: "0 AS price_index" what do you want to show in price_index column? Where does they appear from in your second table?

Comment: @HoTTab1CH they are auto increment index per `product.supplier_catalog_number `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you could achieve what you need through a [12.19 Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), but MySQL currently doesn't have official support.

For example, in MariaDB (>= 10.2.0), [Window Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/window-functions/), you can run a query like the following:

```sql
SELECT
  `products`.`supplier_catalog_number`,
  `prices`.`price`,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `products`.`supplier_catalog_number`) - 1 `price_index`
FROM
  `products`
    INNER JOIN `prices` ON `prices`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
ORDER BY
  `products`.`supplier_catalog_number`,
  `price_index`
LIMIT 10;
```

See [db<>fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e28aa592e697a2b1a66edbbb160727a7).

One way to achieve what you need (MySQL) is to execute the following query, however, it is not the only or efficient way to achieve it:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `prices`, `products`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
    ->   `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `supplier_catalog_number` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prices` (
    ->   `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `price` DECIMAL(9, 4) NOT NULL,
    ->   `product_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`)
    ->     REFERENCES `products`(`id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `products`
    ->   (`supplier_catalog_number`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('00000001600L'),
    ->   ('0023-200'),
    ->   ('0023-300'),
    ->   ('0023-301');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO `prices`
    ->   (`price`, `product_id`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   (287.0000, 1), (243.9500, 1),
    ->   (710.0000, 2), (603.5000, 2),
    ->   (232.0000, 3), (185.6000, 3),
    ->   (289.0000, 4), (231.2000, 4),
    ->   (109.0000, 4), (92.6500, 4);
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `der`.`supplier_catalog_number`,
    ->   `der`.`price`,
    ->   `der`.`price_index`
    -> FROM (
    ->   SELECT
    ->     `products`.`supplier_catalog_number`,
    ->     `prices`.`price`,
    ->     (SELECT @`index` := IF(@`id` = `products`.`id`, @`index` + 1, 0)) `price_index`,
    ->     (SELECT @`id` := `products`.`id`)
    ->   FROM
    ->     (SELECT @`id` := 0, @`index` := 0) `init`,
    ->     `products`
    ->       INNER JOIN `prices` ON `prices`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
    ->   ORDER BY
    ->     `products`.`id`,
    ->     `prices`.`price`
    ->   LIMIT 10
    -> ) `der`
    -> ORDER BY
    ->   `der`.`supplier_catalog_number`,
    ->   `der`.`price_index`;
+-------------------------+----------+-------------+
| supplier_catalog_number | price    | price_index |
+-------------------------+----------+-------------+
| 00000001600L            | 287.0000 |           0 |
| 00000001600L            | 243.9500 |           1 |
| 0023-200                | 710.0000 |           0 |
| 0023-200                | 603.5000 |           1 |
| 0023-300                | 232.0000 |           0 |
| 0023-300                | 185.6000 |           1 |
| 0023-301                | 289.0000 |           0 |
| 0023-301                | 231.2000 |           1 |
| 0023-301                | 109.0000 |           2 |
| 0023-301                |  92.6500 |           3 |
+-------------------------+----------+-------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uemXYgSETBGP2qhMxm8wVn/0).